# I used HTML + JAVAScript, But i can see only JAVAScript

Tags: javascript, html

I used HTML and JAVAscript in one page.

But when i enter the site, and see.

I can see only JAVAscript, not HTML source.

There are few line of HTML string, and one jaascript which creat table

In the page, i can see only table, not few of HTML string

In the body code below,

Only i can see "script ~~/script" Only!
I can't see  this below  in the web page.

```
    <br>
   <a href="./admin.html">Back to admin main page</a> <br>
   <a href="./food_list.html">Go to food list </a> <br>
   <a href="./food_detail_list.html">Go to food detail list </a> <br>
```

This is the body code

```
    <body>
         <br>
        <a href="./admin.html">Back to admin main page</a> <br>
        <a href="./food_list.html">Go to food list </a> <br>
        <a href="./food_detail_list.html">Go to food detail list </a> <br>

        <script>showFoodList();</script>

    </body>
```

this is a whole code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>

        <script language="javascript">

            // this function is used to ask food to server and take a data with json
            function showFoodList(){
                var para = document.location.search;
                fetch("http://gyrjs07.dothome.co.kr/what_to_eat/foodlist.php")
                .then(function(response) {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(function(myJson) {
                    creatTable(myJson);
                });

                }

            function creatTable(data){
                document.write("<table width='80%' border='1' style='margin: auto; text-align: center'>");

                // for문 시작
                for ( var i=0; i<data.length ; i++) {
                    document.write("<tr>");    // <tr> : 행추가
                        // 이중 for문 시작
                        for ( var j=0; j<data[i].length ; j++) {
                            var txt=data[i][j];    // 테이블각 셀에값을 출력
                            document.write("<td>"+ txt +"</td>");     // <td> : 열추가.
                            }
                    document.write("</tr>");
                } //end for i
                document.write("</table>");   // 테이블 태그를 닫는다.
            }

        </script>
    </head>   

    <body>
         <br>
        <a href="./admin.html">Back to admin main page</a> <br>
        <a href="./food_list.html">Go to food list </a> <br>
        <a href="./food_detail_list.html">Go to food detail list </a> <br>

        <script>showFoodList()</script>;

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you use document.write method. It automatically calls document.open which removes all existing nodes in a document.
Documentation for [Document.write()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) and [Document.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/open)

Better approach is append children to some predefined node as it shown in snippet below.

```js
const fakeApiResponse = [
  ["number", "name", "q-ty"],
  ["1.", "soda", "2"],
  ["2.", "beer", "3"],
  ["3", "pizza", "3"]
];

// this function is used to ask food to server and take a data with json
function showFoodList() {
  // Emulate api call to get data
  Promise.resolve(fakeApiResponse).then(function(myJson) {
    creatTable(myJson);
  });
}

function creatTable(data) {
  // Get mountig node from HTML
  const mountingPoind = document.getElementById("food-list");

  // Create Table element and set some attributes
  const table = document.createElement("table");
  table.setAttribute("width", "80%");
  table.setAttribute("border", "1");
  table.setAttribute("style", "margin: auto; text-align: center");

  // Start iterate over data to create table structure
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    createTableRow(table, data[i]);
  }

  // Append table structure to mounting point
  mountingPoind.appendChild(table);
}

// Creates row. Add text call createCell function to generate cells with data
// and append it to parent
function createTableRow(parent, rowData) {
  const row = document.createElement("tr");
  for (let j = 0; j < rowData.length; j++) {
    createCell(row, rowData[j]);
  }
  parent.appendChild(row);
}

// Creates cell. Add text data to it and append it to parent
function createCell(parent, cellData) {
  const cell = document.createElement("td");
  cell.innerText = cellData;
  parent.appendChild(cell);
}

showFoodList();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <br />
    <a href="./admin.html">Back to admin main page</a> <br />
    <a href="./food_list.html">Go to food list </a> <br />
    <a href="./food_detail_list.html">Go to food detail list </a> <br />
    <br />
    <div id="food-list"></div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Got demm! You are my Godness! Thanks god!